# Yii2 How to set time format in FullCallendar?

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, fullcalendar

I'm working on some team project in that framework, where I have one problem with FullCalendar extension.

I need to set time format to be like "8:00" (24-hour) instead of 08 which I get now. The strangest thing is that this problem (displaying time as 2-digit for hour and omitting zeros) appears only in month view, the view for week and day is fine: numeric hour format, and minutes not omitted - just as I want it to be.

I tried to search for some answer, though I didn't find a way to set this. I tried even modify the fullcalendar code itself searching for any "2-digit" or "omitZeroMinute" but changes I made in its `main.js` file seem to not have any effect.

I read this article (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-formatting) in documentation but I don't know how to apply that changes (I'm actually newbie in Yii and even more in this extension).

I just know it should be something like

```
titleFormat: {
    hour: 'numeric',
    omitZeroMinute: false
}
```

Comment: Are you using Yii or Yii2?

Comment: I use Yii2. Sory i forgot to clarify it at the beginning.

Comment: Which fullcalendar extension are you using? There seems to be a few

Comment: added an answer see if it helps

Comment: It's that fullcalendar: https://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: And version is 4.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

You should not change anything in the source files,

### Fullcalendar v3

You can use the [`timeFormat`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/timeFormat) option, uppercase `H` for `24-hour` clock.

See an example below

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  events: [
    {
      title:  'My Event',
      start:  '2010-01-01T14:30:00',
      allDay: false
    }
    // other events here...
  ],
  timeFormat: 'H(:mm)' // uppercase H for 24-hour clock
});
```

### Fullcalendar v4

The option `timeFormat` was Renamed to [`eventTimeFormat`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventTimeFormat). Accepts a date-formatting object instead. Moment.js dependency was removed in this version

Here is an example

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  events: [
    {
      title:  'My Event',
      start:  '2010-01-01T14:30:00',
      allDay: false
    }
    // other events here...
  ],
  eventTimeFormat: { // like '14:30:00'
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit'
  }
});
```

Comment: But how to set this values in module which use this mentioned month view (which seem to be created dynamically, I can't find any construction of this calendar) outside of its declaration?